# jQuery in Wordpress doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to put some simple jQuery code into the Wordpress header (usually just use CSS) but no matter what I try I cannot seem to get it to work. The code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var fadein = 300;
var fadeout = 200;

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnforum img, #btnfacebook img, #btntwitter img, #btnyoutube img, #btnlivestream img, #btncontact img").hover(function() {
 $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, fadein);
 $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
  }, function() {
 $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, fadeout);
});
});
</script>
```

Not much at all. It works fine in a HTML page. I have done a little reading from the Wordpress codex and a few other sources and have tried a few things. Replacing '$' with 'jquery', using '' and so on - but it still won't trigger.

Does anyone have any real knowledge of this? I just need to know where to put what specifically in relation to the code I have as what some tutorials are saying do not really make sense to me.

Thanks

Comment: What errors are you getting? Use Firebug console to get the specific problems, "doesn't work" isn't much to go on... I know WordPress uses Prototype out of the box, could be a problem with polluted namespace.

Comment: What is the value for `fadein` and `fadeout` in the `animate` function? Also whihc page are you putting this in?

Comment: First step: Check out the error console whether there are any errors. It's likely there are some. If you are using Prototype, you won't be able to add jQuery without some tweaking. If there are no errors, second step: Please show which JavaScript files are included in the `head` section.

Comment: The fadein and fadeout are variables as you can see at the top. Animate is.. animate lol, it's part of jQuery.

There are no errors. In fact, I cannot even get a simple alert to work in javscript.

I have jquery 1.4.2 included in the header as I would in a HTML page, just referencing the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it in the a Post you wrote? 
 If so it is possible that WordPress strips out characters or adds slashes to characters to make it "safe to store". 
If it is ANYWHERE else besides the post, it should work normal